# reflection equation differentiation to time

Tags: derivatives

I have a physics problem but it requires calculus I think.

You are in your car driving on a highway at 24 m/s when you glance in the passenger-side mirror (a convex mirror with radius of curvature 150 cm) and notice a truck approaching. If the image of the truck is approaching the vertex of the mirror at a speed of 1.5 m/s when the truck is 2.0 m away, what is the speed of the truck relative to the highway?

I have the equation

(1/s) + (1/s') = 2/R

where R is the constant 1.5

Is my differentiation with respect to time correct, and if not, could someone correct me.

-(1/s^2)(ds/dt) - (1/(s')^2)(ds'/dt) = 0

Comment: The equation has been derived correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to make sure I still remember calculus haha.